# Trying to run models in a for loop

Tags: loops, regression

Pycaret model is throwing errors:

i am trying to run multiple models in a loop:

https://towardsdatascience.com/multiple-time-series-forecasting-with-pycaret-bc0a779a22fe

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'trained_models/AUSTRALIACONVENIENCEBITESIZE.pkl'

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your code, in order to be checked, why the loop does not work. The error says that the model you have defined (*.pkl) could not be found. You can either to produce a new model before looping or save one with the name "AUSTRALIACONVENIENCEBITESIZE.pkl".